# Haskell: definition of counting function producing errors

Tags: haskell

So I defined a 'match' function as follows

```
    let match :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]; match x = map (fromEnum . (==x))
```

Now I'm trying to define a new 'countN' function that counts the matches. When I try

```
    let countN :: a -> [a] -> Int; countN x xs = ? $ match x xs
```

I get errors of the form: 'parse error of input '?''

Comment: Are you compiling the tutor's task as is? It looks like you are meant to come up with the function you are meant to replace `?` with.

Comment: Would you possibly be able to help me with that? I've been unable to figure it out thus far.

Comment: It depends on what you understand and what you don't understand. If you understand the role of `match` in that expression, then you could use `hoogle` to find a function of the necessary type.

Comment: Yes, I know the role of 'match' is to convert the matches in the list to '1' and the rest to '0'. The 'countN' function is to count the number of matches (i.e. the 1's). However, I haven't been able to figure out what to put in place of the '?' yet.

Comment: But do you understand the type of whatever goes in place of `?`. If so, hoogle it; the necessary function is among the top results. If you don't know the type, then that's what you need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting an error because the compiler is parsing `?` as an operator, and it sees two operators in a row, the second being `$`, which is illegal syntax.  It looks like you copy/pasted this from somewhere that had the `?` there as something to fill in, what do you think goes there?

EDIT:

To elaborate, what would you make of an expression like

```
myFunc x = + * ++ / x
```

To humans and any Haskell compiler, this expression makes no sense.  What do all of those operators mean there?  It can't be composition, the types wouldn't line up, and there just aren't enough arguments.  This is the sort of problem the compiler has when it sees `? $ match x xs`.